# Do we need the previous element in a linked list?

Tags: java, collections, linked-list, hashmap

In the implementation of `HashMap`, linked lists are used to represent elements in buckets.
Each Entry has a element to the next Entry. See: [Ref](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/HashMap.java#HashMap.remove%28java.lang.Object%29).  However, in the implementation for the `LinkedList` class, each element has a reference to its previous element and its next element see [Ref](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/LinkedList.java).  Just trying to figure out why `previous` is important in one linked list and not another?

Comment: Because it is used in one and not used in another. Just search the code of `LinkedList` for `previous` to learn why it is important there. There is no `previous` in hash map because of the YAGNI principle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Entry` (internal class of `HashMap`) is not a part of general-use linked list (as `LinkedList` is). It's sole purpose is to iterate over it in forward direction looking for an element. So it does not need a `previous` reference.

Answer (score 1):

the previous reference make the LinkedList a bidirectional List,this makes it possible to reversely iterate on a List .

Comment: Okay, but why is that important for one but not for the other?

Answer (score 1):

The reference to the previous element is not needed in a linked list, stricly speaking. The `java.util.LinkedList` is actually a doubly-linked list. This is needed for an efficient implementation of the following operations:

- [add(E)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#add(E)), which append at the end of the list;
- [getLast()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#getLast()), which retrieves the last element of the list;
- [ListIterator.previous()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html#previous()) which allow traversal of the list in reverse order.

Said operations are of no use for the linked list of Map.Entry.

Note that while `getLast()` is a `LinkedList` adition to the list interface, the two other are required by the said interface.

Comment: I can see how it aids previous. How does it aid add() getLast()?

Answer (score 0):

The LinkedList is a general-purpose implementation. You may want to iterate over it backwards. For Maps, when searching a bucket it `only` iterates forward. Since there is not need to iterate backward, it is not implemented.